# SQL Server - Order by defined hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, hierarchy

I have, for example, the following table:

| Client ID | Function |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | RE |
| 1234 | WE |
| 1234 | SP |
| 1234 | AG |
| 6789 | AG |
| 6789 | WE |

And I want to get only 1 client ID but that obeys the following order/hierarchy:
If the Client ID has Function = 'SP' then I want to get this option first, if it has AG then second, the others are indifferent to the order.

Desired Output:

| Client ID | Function |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | SP |
| 6789 | AG |

How can I reproduce this in a query? Thanks

```
    WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [CLIENT_ID]  ORDER BY FUNCTION ASC) AS rn
                ,[CLIENT_ID]
                , FUNCTION 
    FROM ope.stg_client
    ORDER BY (case when FUNCTION = 'SP' then 1 when FUNCTION = 'AG' then 1  ELSE 2  end) ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS
)
SELECT *
    FROM cte
    WHERE rn = 1
```

Output:

| Client ID | Function |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | AG |
| 6789 | AG |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: @Larnu no, that's what I tried but then the hierarchy that I want is not applied

Comment: So include that attempt so we can explain why it didn't work.

Comment: I included my attempt @Larnu, thanks

Comment: you are almost there, you built a custom order with your case in the ORDER BY clause but it should actually be in the windowed function, `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [CLIENT_ID]  ORDER BY CASE WHEN FUNCTION = 'SP' THEN 1 WHEN FUNCTION = 'AG' THEN 2  ELSE 3 END ASC)`

Comment: @Ockert Yes, I realized that a little later. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

By doing

```
    WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [CLIENT_ID] ORDER BY (
                CASE FUNCTION
                    WHEN 'SP' THEN 0
                    WHEN 'AG' THEN 1
                    ELSE 2
                END) ASC) AS rn
                ,[CLIENT_ID]
                , FUNCTION 
    FROM ope.stg_client
)
SELECT *
    FROM cte
    WHERE rn = 1
```

I was able to get the desire output